# isEqual vs isMatch - Does isMatch ignore the order to nested array elements?

Tags: node.js, lodash

I'm using [lodash](https://lodash.com) for comparing below two objects:

```
obj1 = {
    "_id": "57767",
    "Re": {
        "PropertyTypes": [
            {
                "AllocationID": 13870,
                "Percentage": null,
                "Type": "Hotels",
                "Value": null
            },
            {
                "AllocationID": 13867,
                "Percentage": null,
                "Type": "Industrial",
                "Value": null
            }
        ]
    }
}

obj2 = {
    "_id": "57767",
    "Re": {
        "PropertyTypes": [
            {
                "AllocationID": 13867,
                "Percentage": null,
                "Type": "Industrial",
                "Value": null
            },
            {
                "AllocationID": 13870,
                "Percentage": null,
                "Type": "Hotels",
                "Value": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I see that with `isEqual(obj1, obj2)`, the comparison fails and with `isMatch(obj1, obj2)`, it works fine.

I would like to know if both `isEqual` and `isMatch` work in exactly the same ways except for the fact that the order of the `PropertyTypes` array's elements is ignored by `isMatch` in this case. I did not find this info in [isMatch's documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isMatch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't work in the same way really, _.isMatch only performs a *partial* deep comparison while _.isEqual performs a *full* deep comparison.

So for the example of two simple objects, we get the results below, isMatch returns true since they overlap.

And in your case, the obj1 and obj2 "Re" properties don't have to match at all to get _.isMatch to return true.

```js
let obj1 = {
    "_id": "57767",
    "Re": {
        "PropertyTypes": [
            {
                "AllocationID": 13870,
                "Percentage": null,
                "Type": "Hotels",
                "Value": null
            },
            {
                "AllocationID": 13867,
                "Percentage": null,
                "Type": "Industrial",
                "Value": null
            }
        ]
    }
}

// Remove Re property of obj2 to demonstrate.
let obj2 = {
    "_id": "57767",
    "Re": { 
    }
}

console.log("_.isEqual(obj1, obj2)", _.isEqual(obj1, obj2));
console.log("_.isMatch(obj1, obj2)", _.isMatch(obj1, obj2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I haven't been able to understand the exact difference between partial deep comparison and full deep comparison. Do you mind helping me understand the same with respect to the example I've shared?

Comment: It's all in this "overlap" word (which I explained as "at least"): partial means it's OK if the object being checked has _more_ data as long as it _contains_ the data declared by the controlling parameter (`obj2`, what lodash calls `source` in the doc). In  Terry's case, `isMatch` is asked to check that `obj1` _contains_ an `_id` of value `"57767"` and an object in key `Re`. Contains, not equals: that's what partial is. And it's said deep because the same logic applies to the `Re` sub-object: it must contain at least nothing (`obj2.Re` is empty), but it may contain much more.

Comment: Good explanation @StockOverflaw! I think that another point to make about the difference between a full and partial deep comparision is that partial comparison is less strict and is really indended for a different use case. In the example I give, _.isMatch returns true for the comparison of the "Re" property of obj1 and obj2, despite the fact that "Re" on obj2 is an empty object.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what you mean by "work in exactly the same way", however here's my understanding:

- `_.isMatch` and `_.isEqual` share the same internal logics, `_isMatch` calling said underlying logics with explicit *partial* and *unordered* flags (so I guess we can say they work *quite* the same way)
- I'd say that generally `_isMatch` is to be used to assert an input object - e.g. a configuration - is *at least yet maybe not exactly* well shaped beforehand, whereas `_.isEqual` handles the purest, strictest comparison
- because of this validation-like behavior, there's also the concept of partial flag, which might be a pitfall given the data you show, for instance:

```
obj1 = {
  a: 123,
  b: 456,
  c: 789
};
obj2 = {
  a: 123,
  b: 456
}
_.isMatch(obj1, obj2); // true, `c` wasn't "asserted"
_.isMatch(obj2, obj1); // false, missing value for `c`
```

To extend this to an example closer to your case, and since it's a deep comparison:

```
obj1 = {
  PropertyTypes: [{
    id: 13867
  }, {
    id: 13870
  }]
};
obj2 = {
  PropertyTypes: [{
    id: 13867
  }, {
    id: 13870
  }, {
    id: 11111
  }]
};
_.isMatch(obj1, obj2); // false, missing 11111 value
_.isMatch(obj2, obj1); // true, even though there's one more item in the array
```

Hope this helps!